# Why does the content of child DIVS affect the child height but not not the parent height?

Tags: css, html, height, positioning

```
           <div id="container">
               <div id="sidebar-left">
                  //some content 
               </div>
               <div id ="content">
                //some content
               </div>
            </div>
```

Take the above piece of code for example. The content in the sidebar and the content divs are stretching them out and giving them length - but why on earth is their parent div, "container", also not being stretched out and given length? If it's possible, how do I achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/QA8Z7/6/

Comment: could you put a screenshot or http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @ManuelChoucino
Sure, JSFiddle up.

Comment: Because you `float` the items. Use `overflow: hidden;` on the container.

Comment: Like  PeeHaa said, this will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use clear class after you float some div or overflow hidden in parent div always

```
<div id="container">
      <div id="sidebar-left">some content </div>
      <div id="content">some content</div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is a more elegant solution as it allows me to have elements poking out from the div as opposed overflow:hidden, which also works

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark here and guess that you've got `float` set on `sidebar-left` and `content`, and wondering why the `container` div isn't containing them? If that's the case, there's various ways to ["fix" this problem](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Floats_and_clearing#Clearing); this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best) goes into the various options in great detail.

Edit: Just saw that while I was writing this it's already been figured out, oh well. Nevertheless it might be useful to see the underlying roots of the problem and some alternatives to setting `overflow` on the container.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this is, but if you do

```
#container {
    background-color: red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

​then it works. Hope this helps!